# Preg_match help for finding count

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

HI all 
i have a string

```
<font size="+1"><b>Open Directory Sites</b></font> (1-20 of 10000)<p>
```

i need to get 10000 as answer .. how i use preg_match ??? Note: this is implortant that the multiple occurance of match

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for this particular case, you could use `'/\(\d+\-\d+ of (\d+)\)/'` as the `pattern`.

It matches strings like this `({one-or-more-digits}-{one-or-more-digits} of {one-or-more-digits})` and captures the last `{one-or-more-digits}` into a group (`{}`s added just for clarity's sake here..).

```
$str = '<font size="+1"><b>Open Directory Sites</b></font> (1-20 of 10000)<p>';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/\(\d+\-\d+ of (\d+)\)/', $str, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (1-20 of 10000)
    [1] => 10000
)
```

So, the 10000 you are looking for would be accessible at `$matches[1]`.

---

Edit after your comment: If you have multiple occurrences of `({one-or-more-digits}-{one-or-more-digits} of {one-or-more-digits})`, you can use `preg_match_all` to catch them all. I'm not sure how useful the numbers themselves are without the context in which they occur, but here's how you could do it:

```
$str = '<font size="+1"><b>Open Directory Sites</b></font> (1-20 of 10000)<p>';
$str .= "\n$str\n";
echo $str;
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\(\d+\-\d+ of (\d+)\)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

prints:

```
<font size="+1"><b>Open Directory Sites</b></font> (1-20 of 10000)<p>
<font size="+1"><b>Open Directory Sites</b></font> (1-20 of 10000)<p>
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (1-20 of 10000)
            [1] => (1-20 of 10000)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 10000
        )

)
```

Again, what you're looking for would be in `$matches[1]`, only this time it'll be an array containing 1 or more of the actual values.

Comment: What does it do `(\d+)` without braces?

Comment: .its work fine if the string contain only one (1-20 of 10000) ... but in my case there is a chance of multiple occurance

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to reflect the real situation?

Comment: @sAc I'm not sure I understand your question?